# how to insert many similar records in mysql at a time?

Tags: wildcards, mysql

we know that we can insert multiple records at a time using this query:

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE1` (`First`,`Last`) VALUES ('name1','surname1'),
('name2','surname2'),
('name3','surname3'),
('name4','surname4');
```

but what if we want to add 1000 similar records as above `(name*,surname*)` do we have to write down all the records or we can use something like wildcard? or is there any other solution using mysql (phpmyadmin) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you're only able to do these types of inserts:

```
INSERT INTO table (artist, album, track, length) 
VALUES 
("$artist", "$album", "$track1", "$length1"), 
("$artist", "$album", "$track2", "$length2"),
("$artist", "$album", "$track3", "$length3"), 
("$artist", "$album", "$track4", "$length4"),
("$artist", "$album", "$track5", "$length5");
```

But you can always write a script that will generate the above using whatever regular expressions you desire. The script would then be responsible for expanding the regexes into the appropriate above `INSERT ...`, and then run it.

#### REGEXP operator

You could try generating your patterns ahead of time, or as part of the contents to the `VALUES` command using `REGEXP`.

You can use it often times on the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM products
WHERE sku REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]{2,4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}$'
```

You can read more about this operator on the MySQL website under the [REGEXP docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html), but I've never seen it used in this fashion and have never thought to attempt it myself either. I found the command mentioned in this SO Q&A titled: [Adapting a Regex to work with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873931/adapting-a-regex-to-work-with-mysql).

#### References

- [8.3.2.1 Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html)
- [Multiple mysql INSERT statements in one query php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307618/multiple-mysql-insert-statements-in-one-query-php)
- [Insert multiple records into MySQL with a single query](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/)

Answer (score 0):

As other answers state, you can't, but if you're using PHP+PDO and **prepared statements**, you can reuse your statement with several different params while the machine makes a **cache** of your statement to optimize the whole process. Not to mention it'll take care of the scaping and that stuff. The code might look something like this (PHP):

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:dbname=pdo;host=localhost", "username", "password" );
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$STMT = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES (?,?)");

// Let's say $array is an array of 1000+ different elements
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $STMT->bindParam(1, $value); // You just need to bind the params and execute
    $STMT->bindParam(2, $value); // the statement for every record.
    $STMT->execute();
}

$DBH = NULL;
```

Also, I suggest you use [**Adminer**](http://www.adminer.org/), it's interface is cleaner and it's simplier to mantain/update (it's just a single PHP file with the whole app). Not to mention that phpmyadmin is no longer under development (Adminer is phpmyadmin's present and future).